# добавить данные в массив через POST

Tags: php

```
<form action="sortgoroda.php" method="post">
 <p>Город: <input type="text" name="city" /></p>
 <p><input type="submit" /></p>
</form>

<?php

$city = $_POST['city'];
$array[] = $city;
print_r($array);

?>
```

Не могу добавить данные в массив. Например я добавляю город Москва, он его записывает. А когда второй раз добавляю город, например Киев, он перезаписывается, а не добавляется

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Php` это скриптовой серверный язык. Это означает, что при каждом `HTTP` запросе запускается `php` интерпретатор проверяет ваш скрипт на синтаксические ошибки, запускает и по завершению очищает всю занимаемую оперативную память. Что бы хранить ваши данные есть ряд хранилищ:

- [Cookie](http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.cookies.php) – хранилище в 4КБ на 1 домен в бразуре. Их лучше использовать только для идентификатора сессии т.к. их юзер может удалить, подменить и они посылаются при каждом запросе на сервер, со всеми вытекающими;
- [Сессия](http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.session.php) – хранилище для каждого юзера на сервере. Скорее всего то, что вам нужно. Безопасно, но основывается так же на куки и имеет "лимит жизни";
- [Файловая система](http://php.net/manual/ru/ref.filesystem.php) – очень простой вариант хранения данных, просто в файлах;
- [Базы данных](http://php.net/manual/ru/refs.database.php) – специальные программы, которые дают доступ для записи, хранения и чтения данных. В вебе самая популярная и простая СУБД это [MySql](http://www.mysql.com)
- [Разделяемая память](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.shmop.php) – при большом желании можно писать напрямую в оперативку. Но я пока не встречал реальной необходимости для `php`.

Этот список можно продолжать, но для ваших целей это самое основное.

Answer (score 1):

При каждом запуске скрипта, ваши переменные инициализируются заново, вы должны куда то это дело писать, например в файл или базу данных, а не просто в массив.
Они у вас пишутся в массив, но старые значения то надо где то хранить и подгружать в этот массив при каждом постинге на этот скрипт

**UPDATE**

[Функции для работы с файловой системой](http://www.php.su/functions/?cat=filesystem)

Comment: спасибо за ответ, можете подсказать пример или статью про запись в файл.

Comment: если ответ правильный отметьте его галочкой.

Answer (score 1):

может попробуете так?

```php
<form action="" method="post">
 <p>Город: <input type="text" name="city" /></p>
 <p><input type="submit" /></p>
</form>

<?php

session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['city'])) {
  $array = $_SESSION['city'];
} 

$city = (isset($_POST['city'])) ? $_POST['city'] : '';
$array[] = $city;
print_r($array);

$_SESSION['city'] = $array;

?>
```

Comment: тоже вариант :)